# Compress / Reduce file size of VIDEO

Tags: php, ffmpeg, compression, ffmpeg-php

I currently have a system in place where the user can upload a MP4 file and the same is available for download on mobile devices. But sometimes, the videos are more than 5MB in size and back here in my country, majority of the population uses 2G. So it typically takes 15-20 minutes to download large videos.

Is there any way in which I can compress MP4 files while they are being uploaded and then save them in the folder so that instead of a 5MB video, I get a 2MB video which takes relatively less time to download. File format will **always be MP4 only**.

I know of FFMPEG-PHP, but as far as I read, it only supports extracting information of the video and for video conversion. I could not find any reference for VIDEO COMPRESSION. I would be grateful if you could guide me on this.

Answer (score 3):

Well MP4 is already a compressed video. So what you want to do is converted one compressed video to an other compressed video. Your output will need to have a lower resolution, lower bitrate or whatever works for the videos you get. But conversion with ffmpeg is most likely the way to go.

Comment: Noting the fact that MP4 is already a compressed video, is a very helpful hint.